# UITabBar line between view and tab bar

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there any way to remove black line between view and tab bar?

[image]

Comment: http://felipecypriano.com/2012/02/27/how-to-customize-uitabbar-on-ios-5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to set a custom background image for the tab bar

```
UITabBarController* tab = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[tab.tabBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabBackground.png"]];
```

Comment: What is default width of tabbar in pixels?

Comment: 320 x 49 for iphone (1x). Is derived from UIView, so you can also use frame.size.height or width

Answer (score 0):

I put my tab bar image like :-

[image]

and what I set it on tap bar like:-

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320, 48);
        NSLog(@"%f",frame.size.width);
        UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        // [v setBackgroundColor:DARK_BACKGROUNDTabBar];
        UIImageView *imgView =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
        UIImage *img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar.png"];
        [imgView setImage:img1];
        [v addSubview:imgView];

        [v setAlpha:1];
        [[self.tabBarController tabBar] insertSubview:v atIndex:1];
        [v release];
```

Hope it will be use-full for you.

You can create your own image with 4 or 5 tab and set like above.